# Easiest way to split 2d numpy array in to two 1d arrays?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

how do I get arrays x and y from array a?

a is a 2d array and I need to get x and y which are the columns of a

```
a=[[ 0  1]
  [ 2  3]
  [ 4  5]
  [ 6  7]
  [ 8  9]
  [10 11]]

x =[[0]   
    [2]
    [4]
    [6]
    [8]  
    [10]]

y =  [[1]
     [3]
     [4]
     [7]
     [9]
     [11]]
```

Comment: Use slice to get columns: `x, y = a[:,:1], a[:,1:]`

Answer (score 6, accepted):

your array:-

```
arr=np.array([[0,1],[2,3],[4,5],[6,7],[8,9],[10,11]])
```

your answer:-

```
arr1,arr2=np.split(arr,2,axis=1)
```

Comment: What I actually need is `arr1.flatten()` and `arr2.flatten()` after your code. Can we get these two 1-D arrays directly from `array`?

Answer (score 2):

Try this

```
numpy.split(array, 2, axis=1)
```

Comment: What if I wanted the answer in 1D Array not in 2D array?

Comment: suppose you have 2D array named arr......just use `arr.flatten()` you will get 1D `array`

Comment: Use flatten on each sub array? No.